# Rspec request spec looking for singular named controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have the following routes defined and the following UsersController defined and when I attempt to run spec test that attempts **before { visit signup_path }**, I get the following error:

**ERROR**

```
Failure/Error: before { visit signup_path}
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       uninitialized constant UserController
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
  resources :users
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :users
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  root :to => 'static_pages#help'
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**updated**
**user_pages_spec.rb**

```
 describe "UserPages" do
  subject { page }

  describe "Signup Page" do
    before { visit signup_path}

    it "Should have header Sign-up" do
      should have_selector("h1", text: "Sign-up")
      should have_selector("title", text: "Sign-up")
    end
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector("title", text: "#{user.name} Profile")}
    it { should have_selector("h1", text: user.name)}
  end
end
```

Here is my routes:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
          POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
     user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
          PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
          DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
   signup        /signup(.:format)         users#new
     help        /help(.:format)           static_pages#help
     root        /                         static_pages#help
```

I can go to www.blah.com/signup without an issue.  But the spec is looking for a singular UserController.  I can also substitute "signup_path" for "/users/new" and the test will pass.

Also, wanted to add that originally I created the controller (only) using the rails generator using the singular version.  But I backed it out after I discovered that by using the rails destroy controller script.  Then issued the correct rails generator for the plural version.    Like I said, its like the tests are screwed up, but the actual app.

Comment: What does your `describe` block look like in your spec? You aren't specifying something like `describe UserController` are you?

Comment: I have added the full describe block.  And I don't have anything hard coded.  I did add an additional comment about having generated the singular version first (see notes).

Comment: I am also using Guard/Spork, and after editing the spec_helper.rb file which forced a reload for spork, the test now passes.  Does anyone have an explanation of why that is?